# How to remove applications from start menu that are installed by Wine

Tags: wine, launcher

I installed some applications, using Wine. They appeared in the start menu
I wanted to remove the application, so I removed the folder

[image]

it didn't work so I tried by removing the wine folder but it stayed there, every time i launched it. I then went to `usr/share/applications` but that didn't work either, as it wasn't there.

Is there another way to remove Wine-installed applications?

Comment: .desktop files (launchers) can also be located in your home directory in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: It works! Thanks, please put it as an answer so I may tick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the directory your application is installed, delete that but go to `programfiles/users/startmenu/programs,[applicationfolder]` and delete the folder it should no longer appear in the startmenu.